# How can I find weekend between date range from weekend table in oracle?

Tags: sql, spring, oracle

Here is my oracle table :

```
CREATE TABLE HR_LK_WEEKEND
(
  COMPCODE  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  STRTDTFR  DATE                                NOT NULL,
  EXPRDTTO  DATE,
  HOLICODE  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  HOLIDYNM  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  SEQUNUMB  INTEGER                             NOT NULL,
  ACTVFLAG  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  REMARKSS  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  ROWNUMBR  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  OPRSTAMP  VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)                    NOT NULL,
  TIMSTAMP  DATE                                NOT NULL
);
```

and Data :

```
Insert into HR_LK_WEEKEND
   (COMPCODE, STRTDTFR, EXPRDTTO, HOLICODE, HOLIDYNM, 
    SEQUNUMB, ACTVFLAG, REMARKSS, ROWNUMBR, OPRSTAMP, 
    TIMSTAMP)
 Values
   ('100', TO_DATE('01/01/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/31/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HL021', 'FRI', 
    3, 'Y', NULL, 'HL02102', 'SYSTEM', 
    TO_DATE('08/16/2020 15:12:33', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into HR_LK_WEEKEND
   (COMPCODE, STRTDTFR, EXPRDTTO, HOLICODE, HOLIDYNM, 
    SEQUNUMB, ACTVFLAG, REMARKSS, ROWNUMBR, OPRSTAMP, 
    TIMSTAMP)
 Values
   ('100', TO_DATE('01/01/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/31/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HL019', 'SAT', 
    4, 'Y', NULL, 'HL01902', 'SYSTEM', 
    TO_DATE('08/16/2020 15:14:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;
```

[image]

I want to get weekend name between date range using date column `STRTDTFR` and `EXPRDTTO` between `to_date('01/01/2021', 'DD/MM/RRRR')` and `to_date('31/01/2021', 'DD/MM/RRRR')`.

Please suggest me how can I get this solution.

I want output like this :

```
    Date        Weekend
    ===================
    01/01/2021  = FRI
    02/01/2021  = SAT
    08/01/2021  = FRI
    09/01/2021  = SAT
    15/01/2021  = FRI
    16/01/2021  = SAT
    22/01/2021  = FRI
    23/01/2021  = SAT
    29/01/2021  = FRI
    30/01/2021  = SAT
```

Comment: What does "weekend name" mean? Also, based on data you provided, what is desired output?

Comment: [example](https://rextester.com/KMJLZ60412)